# How do I access subclass variables in a baseclass vector? (for an entity component system)

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, entity

So I have a vector with "Components". I can access the Component variables easily from the vector, but when I add a subclass to the vector, I cant access those variables.

Maybe this is a really bold question and the solution is probably really complicated, but I don't know where to start and what to try so any help is appreciated.

```
struct Component {};
std::vector<Component> components;

struct Transform : Component
{
    int x, y;
};

void Start()
{
    components.push_back(Transform());
    //can't acces x below
    std::cout << components[0].x;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

make the vector just for unique pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;
```

step 2:

```
void Start()
{   
    //add component (pointer to vector)
    components.push_back(std::make_unique<Transform>());
    //cast to Transform
    Transform const* transform = static_cast<Transform*>(components[0].get());

    std::cout << transform->x;
}
```

Comment: Object slicing occurs, you probably want `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;` or `std::variant`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So now how do I add to the vector? "components.push_back(Transform());" doesn't work anymore because the vector requires a pointer right? How do I add a "std::unique_ptr<Component>" to the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have a problem with object slicing, to sort that you could do something like :

```
struct Component {};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;

struct Transform : Component
{
   int x = 0, y = 0;
};

void Start()
{
    components.push_back(std::make_unique<Transform>());
}
```

As for accessing members of `Transform` you have a couple of options.
C++ has built in `rtti` but be warned it's quite slow :

```
Transform const* transform = dynamic_cast<Transform*>(components[0].get());
if(transform != nullptr)
    std::cout << transform.x;
```

Another option is to implement a virtual function from `Component` :

```
struct Component
{
    virtual void Update();
};

struct Transform : public Component
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    virtual void Update() override
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
};

void Start()
{
    components.push_back(std::make_unique<Transform>());
    for(Component& component : components)
    {
        component.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of the dynamic cast but it gives me this error: the operand of a runtime dynamic_cast must have a polymorphic class type

Comment: @Felix You'll have to fix the object slicing error for it to work.

Comment: instead of dynamic cast, it needed to be a static cast! then it all works.

Comment: @Felix `static_cast` works too. But it's a bit more finicky, if you end up `static_cast` ing to `Transform` and the component you've cast is actually something else like `Render` for example then you'll invoke [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your vector stores objects of class `Component`.
What happens in `push_back` is, that the vector creates a new `Component` which is *copied* from your `Transform()` object.

So the first big thing to note here is, that you did not really push a `Transform` object into the vector, thus there is no such `.x`.

Note that in C++, just the line `Transform x{};` creates an object on the stack. Thus `Component y=x;` creates another object and copies its data (which are none in this case, as `Component` is empty) from `x`.
And this is essentially what happens in your code, just a bit hidden with in the vector.